# Python 'NoneType' object has no attribute '...'

Tags: python, python-2.7

i've a problem with python i write this Class

```
class TNode(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
        self._children=[]
    def add(self, c):
        self._children=self._children +[c]
    def children(self):
        t=[]        
        for f in self._children:
            t+=f
        return t
    def height(self):
        h = 1
        for node in self._children:
            h = max(h, node.height() + 1)
        return h
    def count(self):        
        cnt = 1
        for node in self._children:
            cnt += node.count()
        return cnt
    def count_by_name(self, name):
        cbn=0
        for node in self._children:
            cbn+=node.count(name)
        return cbn          
    def paths(self, name):
        pset = set()
        if self.name == name:
            pset.add((name,))
        for node in self._children:
            for p in node.path(name):
                pset.add((self.name,)+p)
        return pset
```

and after write function:

```
def create_tree(d):
    root=TNode(d['name'])   
    for node in (d['children']):
        if len(d['children'])!=0:
            child=TNode(node['name'])
            tree=root.add(child) 
            create_tree(node)
    return tree
```

this is the dictionary:

```
d = {'name':'musica', 'children':
                  [{'name':'rock', 'children':
                                   [{'name':'origini','children':[]},
                                    {'name':'rock&roll','children':[]},
                                    {'name':'hard rock', 'children':[]}]},
                   {'name':'jazz', 'children':
                                   [{'name':'origini', 'children':
                                                       [{'name':'1900', 'children':
                                                                        [{'name':'origini','children':[]}]}]},
                                    {'name':'ragtime', 'children':[]},
                                    {'name':'swing', 'children':[]}]}]}
```

i try to do some operation like: tree.count(), tree.paths() or tree.height() but i have ever the same response `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count/paths...'`

i hope you can help me :)

Comment: It means `tree` is equal to `None`. Look at how you defined tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there's something wrong with your design.

According to your code, `tree` is not a `TNode` instance:

```
def create_tree(d):
    root=TNode(d['name'])   
    for node in (d['children']):
        if len(d['children'])!=0:
            child=TNode(node['name'])
            tree=root.add(child) 
            create_tree(node)
    return tree
```

`tree` is the return value of method `add()`, which is `None`.

You can call `count()` or `paths()` on `root`, but not on `tree`.

Maybe you want to return `root` instead of `tree`?